# Change Layout background continuously

Tags: android, android-layout

I am making an application in which i am changing the the layout background continually like flipping the background, I am implementing the background change using `Activity.runOnUiThread()` function since it is a UI function and waiting for 2 seconds using `Thread().sleep()` but the application only shows the layout color I mentioned in the end.

```
package com.tutorial.flasher;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Bundle;
//import android.os.SystemClock;
//import android.os.SystemClock;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;


public class flasher extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
     LinearLayout llaLayout;
     Thread th = new Thread("ThreadOne");
     Activity _activity = new Activity();


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    llaLayout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.layo);



    Thread t1 = new Thread(new Runnable() {

        public void run() {
            try
            {
                Thread.sleep(2000);
            }
            catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO: handle exception
            }
        }
    });

    t1.start();
    t1.run();
    t1.stop();


     _activity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){
        public void run(){
            llaLayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#00FF00"));

        }
    });
    //t1.currentThread();
    t1.start();
  t1.run();
    t1.stop();

    _activity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){
        public void run(){
                                //Color BLUE of layout
            llaLayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#0000FF"));

        }
    });


}
```

}

Both the UI changes and Thread staring would be happening in a loop(which is not shown) but still the application is changing the layout color only once.
Thanks,
Sid

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. You should not `new` Activity, Activity is created by Android system.
2. Call `Thread.start` will start the thread, there is no need to call `Thread.run`.

`Activity.runOnUiThread` maybe not the best way to archive this, try `Handler`. Here is sample code:

```
public class BroadcastActivity extends Activity {

    public static final int CHANGE_BGCOLOR = 1;

    private LinearLayout llaLayout;

    private Handler handler = new Handler() {
        public void handleMessage(android.os.Message msg) {
            if (msg.what == 1) {
                String color = (String) msg.obj;
                llaLayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor(color));
                String nextColor = ""; // Next background color;
                Message m = obtainMessage(CHANGE_BGCOLOR, nextColor);
                sendMessageDelayed(m, 200);
            }
        }
    };

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        llaLayout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.layo);
        String nextColor = ""; // Next background color;
        Message m = handler.obtainMessage(CHANGE_BGCOLOR, nextColor);
        handler.sendMessageDelayed(m, 200);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer Tony, Sorry it took me a few days to try the answer, I am still struggling to get the functionality working in a repeated fashion, do you have any recommendation on how can I get that working. Thanks.

Comment: Here is a tutorial about timed UI updating, hope it can help. http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/timed-ui-updates.html